# Rundeck import project blocked

Tags: rundeck

I trying to export rundeck projects from GCP instance to another with the exact same GCP instance image, but the import failing with the error

```
File Transfer Blocked
The file you are trying to download or upload has been blocked in accordance with company policy. Please contact your system administrator if you believe this is an error.
File name: XXXX_gce_prod-20231128-131947.rdproject.jar
```

although my user is admin, and it's the same rundeck version and this is the admin policy

```
description: Admin, all access.
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create all kinds
    - allow: import
    - allow: export
  adhoc:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/running/killing adhoc jobs
  job: 
    - allow: '*' # allow read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/run for all nodes
by:
  group: admin

---

description: Admin, all access.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow create of projects
  project:
    - allow: '*' # allow view/admin of all project
    - allow: import
    - allow: exports
  project_acl:
    - allow: '*' # allow admin of all project-level ACL policies
  storage:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create/update/delete for all /keys/* storage content
by:
  group: admin
```

What I'm missing? is there a specific configuration to export/import projects?

Comment: Might this be a bit more appropriate for the DevOps stackexchange?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Hi. Where have you seen that message? (GUI, via API, RD-CLI) How do you try to export your project? please elaborate.

Comment: The error appears when trying to import(GUI) the exported file from the GUI.

@m  But another way worked with me, which is importing and exporting from rundeck-cli, and another issue happened while trying the cli is that it always reject the username & password approach, I have to login from the GUI generate a token and use it in the CLI.